# Select Query Display First and Last Time

Tags: mysql, select

This is my current table

[image]

Is there select query that i can use to display first time and the last time of date? I'm expecting result like the table below.

[image]

Comment: where is your primary key

Comment: you can but you need to tell which of the value of column Name,department is to be selected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  Day, 
        Date, 
        Department, 
        Name,
        MIN(`Time In`) `Time In`, 
        MAX(`Time Out`) `Time Out`
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY  Day, Date, Department, Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  Day, 
        Date, 
        Department, 
        Name,
        A.MIN_TIME,
        B.MAX_TIME 
FROM    tableName
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Date, MIN(`Time In`) AS MIN_TIME FROM tableName GROUP BY Date) AS A 
           ON tableName.Date = A.Date
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Date, MAX(`Time Out`) AS MAX_TIME FROM tableName GROUP BY Date) AS B 
     ON tableName.Date = B.Date
GROUP BY Date
```